# Integration testing for reading a file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

I want to make sure that my C# program reads a file as expected. How should I test this? I am assuming I just call my function (which accesses the file system) and see the output when a file exist and when it doesn't. Should I instead abstract the file system out?

Should I even bother testing this (since I am basically testing if `StreamReader.ReadLine` works)?

My function looks like this (filePath, filePath2, a and b are arguments to the function)

```
try
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filePath);

    a = tr.ReadLine();
    b = tr.ReadLine();
    tr.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    error = GetError(ex);
}
if (error != "") {
    File.WriteAllText(filePath2+"Error.txt", error);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two most common approaches: facade for all file IO operations (so you can mock it) or refactor code that you only need to test pieces that take easy to mock objects like `Stream`.

Sample second approach: refactor your code into piece that deals with getting stream and another one that actually read the data:

```
public class MyClass 
{
  .............
  string a;
  string b;
  public ReadTheData(Stream stream)
  {
    try
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);

        a = tr.ReadLine();
        b = tr.ReadLine();
        tr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // awful practice... Don't eat all exceptions
        error = GetError(ex);
    }
    if (error != "") {
       // whatever log infrastructure you have, need to be mock-able for tests 
        Logger.Log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can unit test `ReadTheData` method without any access to file system by passing filled out `MemoryStream` or even mocked out stream.